# Export variables from .env file and get them from os.environ without python-dotenv

Tags: python, environment-variables

I want to use couple env variables in my python script. I created `.env` file with:

```
TEST='test'
```

then create `main.py`:

```
import os
print(os.getenv("TEST"))
print(os.environ['TEST'])
```

execute in same dir:

```
$ source .env
$ echo $TEST
test
```

then run:

```
$ python3 main.py
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/temp/pt/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(os.environ['TEST'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TEST'
```

Why in this case `os.getenv` is not work and work only after `export TEST=test` executing or with `python-dotenv` module using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Don't use `source` to process dotenv files; they are not shell scripts.

---

The immediate problem is that `source` does not *export* any of the variables defined by the file; you are only defining regular shell variables that do not appear in the environment of the new Python process.

You can work around that by enabling the `-a` option to auto-export any variables defined in the file.

```
$ set -a
$ source .env
$ python3 main.py
test
test
```

However, the bigger problem here is that `.env` files are *not* shell scripts. The quoting rules followed by `dotenv` are different. Compare:

```
$ cat .env
TEST=test echo hello
$ cat main.py
import os
import dotenv


x = dotenv.dotenv_values('.env')

print(os.getenv("TEST"))
print(x['TEST'])
$ set -a
$ source .env
hello
$ python3 main.py
None
test echo hello
```

Sourcing the file does not define a variable `TEST`; instead, it executes the `echo` command that ignores the value of `TEST` set only for *its* environment.

Processing the file with `dotenv` produces a variable named `TEST` set to the full string `test echo hello`.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. pip install python-dotenv
2. Import the package in your python script:

   - from dotenv import load_dotenv
   - import os
3. Load the environment variables from the .env file:

   - load_dotenv()
4. my_var = os.getenv('TEST')